# Angular Material "search" component

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-design

I am using angular material 10.x and looking all over for a search component to match material here:

https://material.io/archive/guidelines/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search

[image]

I have tried with no luck:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input matInput type="search">
</mat-form-field>
```

Looks like back in the day of angular material 2 this fairly easy to replicate with just elevation.  However the input design has changed a ton.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-google-search-k1znf4?file=index.html

Is there a way to replicate the search component from the design docs with angular material out of the box?

Comment: Out of the box Angular Material search bar component? Unfortunately, no. Which I agree is frustrating. If you're building hybrid mobile apps though using Angular you might give Ionic a try. They do have a nice built in [SearchBar Component](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/searchbar)

Comment: Yeah that is frustrating. Especially for some thing so widely used through the material spec docs.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, like it is in the Material Design spec, no, but you could use a library like AMSUI, which is specialized in search UI created with Angular Material.
A lot of the best practices from Material and also search UX/UI experts are used to develop the UI there -->
https://dev.redlink.io/amsui/?path=/docs/searchfield-field--default